# How to make line height match font height?

Tags: html, css

I've tried setting my line-height to `1em`, however, there is still some space above and below the font (about 3px):

[image]

How can I set the line-height of my site to be exactly that of the font height?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uovjzrn6/1/

HTML:

```
Hello, world!
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: That is by default. line-height is always equal to its font-size. I suppose you are looking for `line-height: 1`.

Comment: @minitech The only reason I want the line-height to match the letters is to make my margins cleaner in the CSS (i.e. `20px` or `25px` rather than `11px` or `17px`).

Comment: @Mr_Green What can I do to the line-height to make it the height of the font letters, i.e. "H"?

Comment: By the way, the space you see above the letters is the room for the diacritics. ȞȄĹĹÔ ŴÕŘĹĎ.

Answer (score 3):

```
line-height: 0.75;
```

It saved may days.

Comment: ```
line-height: 0.70;
``` 

This is exact

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following sample `div` HTML5/CSS3:

HTML

```
<div id = "sample">
    Hello, world!
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#sample
{
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    margin-top:-3px;
}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: There's still 3 pixels above and bellow the letters: http://i.imgur.com/mq8LJaW.png

Comment: You are right. Adding margin-top:-3px; actually did the job. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right using `line-height: 1` (*without unit*) as stated in your fiddle.

As stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> The used value is this unitless  multiplied by the element's **font size**. The computed value is the same as the specified . In most cases this is the preferred way to set line-height with no unexpected results in case of inheritance.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uovjzrn6/4/)

Comment: Even with `line-height: 1`, there is still 3px of space above and below the letters. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uovjzrn6/5/. Image: http://i.imgur.com/QlfHxIB.png.

Comment: @user4913694 The space is actually by default. IMO, removing it is wrong. maybe you are solving a problem in wrong way.

Comment: Why are you telling the OP that their requirements are wrong? That is not helpful at all.

Comment: The top and bottom space are for up and bottom tail letters if I understand correctly. I think I said so to let OP think about their strategy again to fix this.

Answer (score -3):

```
margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;
```

That should do it for ya